# pass value of datepicker to function

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, input, datepicker

User selects a value from a datePicker and clicks the 'OK' button. I want to pass the value in the datePicker to the confirmExtendTrial function. '4' is only dummy data

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="datePicker"></p>
<input type="button" value="OK" id="confirmExtendTrialBtn" class="edit red btn" onclick="confirmExtendTrial('4')"/>
```

something like...

```
onclick="confirmExtendTrial($('input[name="datepicker"]').val();)"/>
```

Comment: like this `"confirmExtendTrial($("input#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd, mm, yy' }))" `;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it out

```
var confirmExtendTrial = function(date) {
console.log(date);
}

$('#confirmExtendTrialBtn').on('click', function(){
confirmExtendTrial($('#datepicker').val());
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qzzfxm31/)

Answer (score 0):

Try Below

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="datePicker" name="datePicker"></p>
 <input type="button" value="OK" id="confirmExtendTrialBtn" class="edit red btn" onclick="confirmExtendTrial(this.form.datepicker.value)"/>
```

Note: I added `name` to date picker and then passed it value to function.

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```
onclick="confirmExtendTrial($("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat:'dd, mm, yy' });)"/>
```